# How to assign empty string if the value is null in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following LINQ query to get a set of data.

```
var fields = from row in datarows
from field in row
from col in columnnames
where field.Key == col
select new { ColumnName = col, FieldValue = field.Value };
```

The problem is that my code that handle the fields after this query fails because `field.Value` of some rows are returning `null`.

My goal is to assign an empty string if `null` is detected.

Something like `if field.Value == null, then field.Value = ""`

Is it possible to do so in linq query?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`:

```
FieldValue = field.Value ?? ""
```

Comment: hey @Jon any specific reason using "" over string.Empty?

Comment: @PSL: 10 chars less to type.

Comment: Is there a way where I can do this with integers?

Comment: @CássioGalvão: Can you be more specific? Value types cannot be `null` so what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @Jon, It works with strings, but if 'field.Value' is an integer, I get the message: "Operand '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'. How do I set default values of integer types? I'm using linq

Comment: @CássioGalvão: What does "default" mean with integers? When would the default kick in?

Comment: Well, the linq query should return 0 for integer fields which have no value

Comment: @CássioGalvão: The thing is that integer fields *always* have a value.

Comment: @Jon Sorry for not being clear. I'm using a nullable integer type and I want to 'replace' a null value for a zero value.

Comment: @CássioGalvão: So you want something like `int? x = value == 0 ? null : value`.

Answer (score 6):

```
FieldValue = field.Value ?? String.Empty
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`null-coalescing operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
select new { ColumnName = col, FieldValue = field.Value ?? string.Empty };
```

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

Answer (score 4):

FieldValue = field.Value == null ? "" : field.Value

Comment: ...all answers better than mine. Learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>[??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)</kbd> operator to return Empty string in case of null

```
var fields = from row in datarows
from field in row
from col in columnnames
where field.Key == col
select new { ColumnName = col, FieldValue = (field.Value ?? string.Empty) };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = from row in datarows
from field in row
from col in columnnames
where field.Key == col
select new { ColumnName = col, FieldValue = field.Value == null ? string.Empty: field.Value};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also learned that if you are concatenating two fields in a linq field assignment and you are using the null-coalescing operator on only one of the fields, then you need to put parentheses around the field statement as such:

```
StreetAddr = customer.StreetAddr + ", " + (customer.Suite ?? "")
```

However, this code is not so great either because if the "Suite" field is null, then I still got that comma-space ", " hanging out after the "StreetAddr" field. Wish I knew a way to fix that?

Comment: So this is one way to fix that:
StreetAddr = customer.StreetAddr + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Suite) ? "" : ", " + customer.Suite)

Comment: Now some may argue that it's bad to concatenate fields in linq field assignments, and that I should use properties in the view model to concatenate fields instead. I agree, but sometimes I'm lazy and do it anyway. :-)